# Ubuntu Touch Qt3D 2.0 crashes on start

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, crash

I've been trying to develop something in QML3D and while my app is running well on desktop, I can't get it working on my tablet (even thought for example Qt3D cylinder from the software center - https://github.com/Sturmflut/ubuntu-touch-qt3d-cylinder - is working just well).

I've come down to the easiest application having only the emplty viewport but it still crashes on my tablet. Here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Qt3D 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1

/*!
    \brief MainView with a Label and Button elements.
*/

MainView {
    // objectName for functional testing purposes (autopilot-qt5)
    objectName: "mainView"

    // Note! applicationName needs to match the "name" field of the click manifest
    applicationName: "com.ubuntu.developer.zubozrout.3d-car"

    /*
     This property enables the application to change orientation
     when the device is rotated. The default is false.
    */
    automaticOrientation: true

    // Removes the old toolbar and enables new features of the new header.
    useDeprecatedToolbar: false

    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    Page {
        title: i18n.tr("Simple")

        Viewport {
            id: viewport
            width: 100
            height: 100
            fillColor: "#8bd"
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why it crashes please? Each time I try to run it on my tablet a black loading screen appears and then it gets me back to my home screen. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Well, I've just found it crashes because of this: import Qt3D 2.0 ... but I have no idea how to solve that :/

Answer (score 1):

QML3D is no longer developed and therefore not supported by Ubuntu Touch.